# WordPress, minify static text from a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php function in my `function.php` file like this:

```
function sample() {
    echo '$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
              items: {
                  src: 'path-to-image-1.jpg'
              },
          type: 'image'
         });';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'sample');
```

When the string is printed in the HTML code is exactly the same (rightly). Can I, just for this portion of code, minimize by eliminating all spaces and word wrap?

The result I want is this:

```
$('#some-button').magnificPopup({items:{src:'path-to-image-1.jpg'},type:'image'});
```

Comment: `echo "$('#some-button').magnificPopup({items:{src:'path-to-image-1.jpg'},type:'image'});" ` ?

Comment: i can give you a basic regex, but be careful that it will remove spaces in strings too: `preg_replace('/\s|\n|\r/', '', $yourText);`

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just replace all space/newlines with nothing and you are good to go. Keep in mind(!) tho, that that following code replaces ALL speak unwanted and needed ones. But for your given input it works fine.

```
$str = "$('#some-button').magnificPopup({
              items: {
                  src: 'path-to-image-1.jpg'
              },
          type: 'image'
         });";

print preg_replace('~\s~m', '', $str); // prints $('#some-button').magnificPopup({items:{src:'path-to-image-1.jpg'},type:'image'});
```